# Request to server : NSMutableURLRequest for iOS works but HttpPost for Android doesn't

Tags: android, ios, http-post, nsmutableurlrequest

I know that's a really localized question but I have really no idea of what I'm doing wrong with this Android request (simply trying to send some data to server).

First here is what I'm doing with my iOS app (this works well) :

```
NSString *string = @"param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3";
NSData *postData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:cookieSet forHTTPHeaderField:@"Set-Cookie"];
[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
connEnvoi = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Nothing more, and it works perfectly, returning 1 as expected by the server.

Now what I'm doing with my Android app (same server of course) is this :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myURL);

httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/html");
httppost.addHeader("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "val1"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "val2"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3", "val3"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

BasicResponseHandler brh = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, brh);
```

And responseBody returns 0 every time... I have really no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

If you wonder why, I don't set `Content-Length` header in my Android request because it makes me getting a `ClientProtocolException`.

Any help is appreciated and thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 0):

This might save you some time:

https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/github/kevinsawicki/http/HttpRequest.java

You can just drop this class in your project, and it does HTTP post with zero effort.  Your code will look something like this:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("param1", "val1");
params.put("param2", "val2");
params.put("param3", "val3");
String response = HttpRequest.post(url, params, true).body();
```

There are also methods where you can get the HTTP response code, raw stream, etc should you need it, but body() gives you the String contents.  Also, gzip compression support, ignore connection errors, etc are easily added to the method chain.

Comment: That's true, thanks for this link, but something is still not working and I keep getting 0 as the result with Android...